# Ошибка в скрипте javascript

Tags: javascript

Почему-то, при установке дат, не обрабатыватся запрос! Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Расписание занятий</title>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            <!-- //
            function ident(mont) {
                var s
                switch (mont) {
                    case 0:
                        s = "январь";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        s = "февраль";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        s = "март";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        s = "апрель";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        s = "май";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        s = "июнь";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        s = "июль";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        s = "август";
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        s = "сентябрь";
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        s = "октябрь";
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        s = "ноябрь";
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        s = "декабрь";
                        break;
                }
                return s
            }

            function rasp(obj) { // дата начала работы группы
                var d = new Date(obj.begy.value, obj.begm.value, obj.begd.value)
                // дата окончания работы группы
                var w = new Date(obj.endy.value, obj.endm.value, obj.endd.value)
                // дата текущего занятия
                var t = new Date(obj.begy.value, obj.begm.value, obj.begd.value)
                var s = ""
                // выбранный пользователем день работы
                var n = obj.dt.value
                // сформированная дата дня первого занятия
                var k = d.getDate() + Number(n) - Number(d.getDay())
                if (n < d.getDay()) k += 7
                t.setDate(k)
                var s1 = "Дни занятий: " + "\n"
                // scur - дата предполагаемого текущего занятия
                var scur
                var s = s1
                // поиск дат занятий
                while (t.getYear() <= w.getYear()) { // формирование даты очередного занятия
                    scur = +t.getDate() + " " + ident(Number(t.getMonth())) + " " + t.getYear() + "\n"
                    if (t.getYearf) < w.getYear()) {
                    s += scur
                } else {
                    if (t.getMonth() < w.getMonth()) {
                        s += scur
                    } else {
                        if (t.getMonth() == w.getMonth()) {
                            if (t.getDate() < w.getDate()) {
                                s += scur
                            } else {
                                if (t.getDate() == w.getDate()) {
                                    s += scur;
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                k = t.getDate() + 7
                t.setDate(k)
            }
            if (s == s1) alert("Проверьте даты начала и конца занятий")
            else obj.res.value = s
            }
            //-—>
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<h4 align='center'>Формирование расписания занятий</h4>
<form name="form1">
    <table border='3' align='center'>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Начало курсов
        </th>
        <th>
            Конец курсов
        </th>
        <th>
            Расписание
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre>
                 число <input type="text" name="begd" size='10)'>
                месяц
                <select name="begm" size='1'>
                    <option value='0'>январь
                    <option value='1'>фeвpaль
                    <option value='2'>март
                    <option value='3'>апрель
                    <option value='4'>май
                    <option value='5'>июнь
                    <option value='6'>июль
                    <option value='7'>aвгуст
                    <option value='8'>сентябрь
                    <option value='9'>октябрь
                    <option value='10'>ноябрь
                    <option value='11'>декабрь
                </select>
                 год <input type="text" name="begy" size='10' value='2012'>
            </pre>
        </td>
        <td>
            <pre>
                 число <input type="text" name="endd" size='10'>
                месяц
                <select name="endm" size='1'>
                    <option value='0'>январь
                    <option value='1'>фeвpaль
                    <option value='2'>март
                    <option value='3'>апрель
                    <option value='4'>май
                    <option value='5'>июнь
                    <option value='6'>июль
                    <option value='7'>август
                    <option value='8'>сентябрь
                    <option value='9'>октябрь
                    <option value='10'>ноябрь
                    <option value='11'>декабрь
                </select>
                 год <input type="text" name="endy" size='8' value='2012'>
            </pre>
        </td>
        <td rowspan='2'>
            <textarea cols='20' rows='8' name='res'></textarea><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='right'>
             Выберите день занятий:
            <select name='' dt size='1'>
                <option value='0'>воскресенье
                <option value='1'>пoнeдeльник
                <option value='2'>вторник
                <option value='3'>среда
                <option value='4'>четверг
                <option value='5'>пятница
                <option value='6'>суббота
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='left'>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value='Сформировать' onclick="rasp(form1)"><br>
        </td>
        <td align='right'>
            <input type="reset" value='Отменить'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я нифига не понял (ц).

Оформите код нормально.

Comment: как то не особо получается нормально оформить
под чертой код, над чертой просьба

Comment: Ооооо получилось! переоформил, гляньте пожалуйста может кто что найдет

Comment: var scur var s=s1 - что вы хотели этим сказать? var scur, s; s = s1; ?

Comment: да хотел чтоб s=s1

Comment: @maximka88 установите JetBrains WebStorm IDE или на худой конец Macromedia Dreamweawer

Answer (score 1):

Писать надо внимательней, код форматировать по человечески, тогда проблем из-за опечаток будет меньше. И находить их будет проще.
И еще, попробуйте инструменты разработчика в Google Chrome, вам понравится!

1)

```
var scur var s=s1
```

Неправильно, наверно вы хотели

```
var scur; var s=s1
```

2)

```
if(t.getYearf)<w.getYear())
```

Неправильно, куда после getYearf открывающая скобка делась? И откуда взялась f ?

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь к [[@Павел Вершинин](/users/2927/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD)](/users/2927/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD), плюс

```
<select name='dt' size='1'>
```

вместо

```
<select name='' dt size='1'>
```

---

```
    function ident(mont) {
    var months = ["Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь","Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь"];
        return months[mont];
    }
```

---

```
scur = +t.getDate()...
```

заменить на

```
scur += t.getDate()...
```

---

Вообщем, [[@maximka88](/users/9247/maximka88)](/users/9247/maximka88), пользуйтесь дебаггером JS. Если уж такие проблемы - пишите по строчке и отлаживайте каждый свой шаг, следите за правильностью и чистотой кода.

Answer (score 0):

по клику на кнопке в функцию rasp() передается неинициализированная переменная form1.
гдубже в код не заглядывал, но если важно передавать в эту функцию имя формы то хотя бы так:

```
onclick="rasp('form1');"  
// а в самой функции получить ссылку на этот объект:
function rasp(obj) { // дата начала работы группы
    var myForm = document.getElementById(obj);
```

и тогда уже можно вытаскивать из формы остальные элементы через ссылку myForm

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (t.getYearf) < w.getYear()) {
```

69 строчка, у вас тут не хватает скобки(

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = new Date(obj.begy.value, obj.begm.value, obj.begd.value);

scur = + t.getDate() + " " + ident(Number(t.getMonth())) + " " + t.getYear() + "\n";
```

Вот эту вот `t.getYear() + "\n"` никак заменить незя?

Comment: как то мой браузер не выдаёт мне ошибок при выполнении, пользуюсь firefox 16

Comment: Shift+f2. Пункты - "Веб консоль" и "Отладчик"

Comment: Очень кстати странно, что не работает. У меня работает [такой](http://pastebin.com/pu9ADais), но коряво с годом. Может я слепой

Comment: коряво с годом, это уже что то, у меня вон вообще не реагирует на кнопку сформировать!

Comment: @maximka88, [Раз](http://i.imgur.com/VfsSI.png) и [Два](http://jsfiddle.net/6yFy3/)

Comment: Позитивненько, а можно я твой скрипт попробую подправить?

Comment: @maximka88, это твой скрипт, правь на здоровье:)